# Common characters in One Piece and Pirates of Caribbean

Tags: one-piece

Blackbeard exist in both the worlds, one piece as well as the Pirates of Caribbean movie.

Are there any other characters who exist in both the worlds? Or is there any other character shown in Pirates of Caribbean which is similar to the one shown in One Piece?

Comment: Blackbeard is based off an [actual person](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blackbeard). Lots of pirate stories and mythos feature and are inspired by well-known pirates of real life. They characters may have similar archetypes or name, but they are fundamentally different from one another. You are essentially comparing two series that only vaguely resemble each other (by being about pirates).

Comment: With what ʞɹɐzǝɹ said in mind, you can modify your question to ask for real life references of the characters in One PIece.

Answer (score 1):

The legend of [Davy Jones](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Davy_Jones%27_Locker) is featured in PoC, while his name is referenced on Davy Back Fight in OP.

The concept of a Pirate King appears in both stories (Elisabeth Swan and Gol D Roger).

Amongst the mythical creatures that exist in both worlds (mermaids, walking skeleton, etc) I think the Kraken deserves special mention.

Answer (score 0):

There's Davy Jones tale with the underwater ship, in both One Piece and PotC, fantasy creatures (fishmen, mermaids, kraken, skeletons), Blackbeard you already mentioned him. One piece has more real life based characters tho. Like Bellamy, that was a real pirate, Alvida (based on the legendary female pirate Alwida), Jewelery Bonney, Drake, Capone, Charlotte Linlin (shares name with 2 famous female pirates), Kidd, Bartholomew, etc.